# Divide-by-3 with square output?

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I'm thinking of making an 8MHz about-square clock starting from a 24MHz about-square clock. All signals are CMOS with 3.3V(±10%) power.

What are my options? I'd like it low-power, cheap and easy to source, compact.

Note: the divide-by-N [74HC4059](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4059_CNV.pdf#page=8) does not match my "8 MHz *about-square* clock" requirement; the output duty cycle is about 1/3.

Update: I located that [On Semi application note](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8001-D.PDF#page=2) trying to do what I want, except that's using <strike>a lot of circuitry</strike> more ICs than in my dreams. I wish that divide-by-3 function existed pre-integrated...
[image: AND8001-D figure 2]

Update following [comment about the lack of symmetry requirement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/174420/22496#comment356297_174445): the available 24MHz at input has t<sub>lo</sub>>16.5ns, t<sub>hi</sub>>16.5ns, and negligible jitter. The output signal should have t<sub>lo</sub>>50ns, t<sub>hi</sub>>50ns, and no long-term drift. Thus if my math is right, in the above circuit I have to keep the difference of delay between (rising-input-edge to rising-output-edge) and (falling-input-edge to falling-output-edge) within ±8ns (with 166ps engineering margin).

Comment: Standard logic being only fundamental digital gates (AND, OR, NOT) ? Because you can get divide by N ICs already to go or you can get up a counter with some discrete logic on the side.

Comment: EXOR and divide by 4 = slightly asymmetrical divide-by-3.

Comment: I think what is in the On Semi app. note is about as little circuitry as possible for a "neat" solution. A different approach would be to first make the 1/3 dutycycle signal and then "fix" that to be 1/2 duty cycle but you'd end up with at least as much components.

Comment: I've undeleted my answer, and modified it to incorporate the suggestion you made in your comment.  Even with the additional part, I think its still a good way to accomplish this with a guaranteed 50-50 duty cycle.

Comment: The 74HC4059 at 3.3v has an [fMAX](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4059_CNV.pdf#page=9) right around 24MHz and certainly will fail with temperature changes. A [74HC00](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT00.pdf#page=5) has a max transition and propagation of ~50nS at 3.3v. Given that the entire period of a 24MHz cycle is 41.667nS, that isn't going to work either. You'll have to increase your supply voltage or look at a faster family of IC's, perhaps such as the [AHC](http://www.nxp.com/products/logic/family/AHC_T/) series.

Comment: Unless there is some special reason why the 8MHz clock needs to have a defined phase relative to the 24MHz clock, then it's probably much simpler, smaller, and cheaper to just purchase an 8Mhz oscillator.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement the ON Semi circuit with only three small packages. Two 74HC74 dual D flip-flops and a 74HC02 quad 2-in NOR gate. There's a FF left over so you could also get 4MHz or 12MHz simultaneously.

Recall that an AND gate is the same as a NOR with each input inverted, so just use the Q outputs rather than the /Q outputs for the AND gate.

You might be able to further reduce it to two packages using a 4-bit synchronous counter but I doubt you'll get much lower in BOM cost (42 cents US in 100's at Digikey for the three)

Comment: Good point about being able to use either the Q or /Q outputs as needed to avoid inverters.

Comment: Yes. One issue is that I need to invert the clock for (at least one of) the D gates, and the associated delay will contribute to imbalance of the output. If only we had negative-going-clock D-gate; or perhaps using a JK flip-flop?

Comment: The propagation delay of the right-hand flip-flop also contributes to imbalance. If you really need close to exact 50% duty cycle you should use Olin's PLL method and follow it up by a flip-flop to get 50%. You'll still get some jitter, of course. There are clock synthesizer ICs that integrate some of this, but most are aimed at higher frequencies and very high performance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert 24MHz square clock to 48MHz pulse train - one pulse on every edge. A XOR gate with a few gate delays in one input will do that nicely.
2. Divide the pulse train by 3 to get a non-square 16 MHz rectangular signal.
3. Divide that by 2 to get 8 MHz square wave.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PLL (phase locked loop) to multiply the original frequency by 2.  This allows dividing by 3 that doesn't need to be square, then followed by a divide by 2 to yield a square output.

Comment: Is this going to be simpler/cheaper/smaller than the circuit from On Semi posted in the question?

Comment: I have no idea since that's for the OP to determine.  I generally don't follow links in questions, unless it's a datasheet about a part being directly asked about.  It's not my homework to do.  I'm just giving the OP a general idea.

Comment: The OP posted the circuit from On Semi (three FF's plus some glue logic) in the question.  You didn't have to follow a link.  Anyhow the OP thought that was too much circuitry.  I wish him luck.

Comment: @tcros: Again, as in this case, it's usually not worth reading the whole question.  I looked at that circuit briefly, but it seemed irrelevant since it doesn't really provide a square output.  Note that some of the output edges are derived from the input rising edge, some from the falling edge.  That's not square.  If that was good enough you could use a edge-to-glitch converter to double the frequency, then divide from there.

Comment: Look again -- actually the output is square -- the on period is 1.5 cycles of the 24 MHz clock, and off period is also 1.5 cycles.  It has to be a alternating rising/falling edge because of dividing by a odd number.  Note the rising edge of the output always lines up with a rising edge of the input.

Comment: @trcos: No, the output isn't square due to inevitable assymetry between rising and falling edges.

Comment: +1 This deserves an upvote, since it's the only way to get what the OP apparently wants but did not explicitly state (very close to 50% duty cycle rather than 50%-ish).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The OP's requirement is "8 MHz *about-square* clock", unclear what that really means and whether the circuit posted in the question is close enough.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: If you want to play the "inevitable asymmetry" game, then a true 50% duty cycle is inherently unattainable from any source because of the differences in the rising and falling edges of the output waveform.

Answer (score 2):

As a derivation of tcrosley's answer, the [PIC18F2550 (24Pin SOIC or DIP)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf) has a nice PLL block. This can take a 24MHz input, prescale it by a factor of 12 down to 4MHz (PLLDIV=111), feed that into a PLL which will step it up to 96MHz, then feed that through a postscaler with a factor of 6 (CPUDIV=11) to make 16MHz.

This can then feed the Timer1 module which can be configured to toggle a CCP pin on compare match and reset the timer - you set the compare value as zero which means every clock cycle a match will occur and the CCP pin will toggle thus producing a 50% duty cycle 8MHz signal (I know this works in AVRs, so I am assuming it will also work in PICs).

A bit contrived, but it is a single chip approach. Plus it means you have a PIC running at 16MHz to use for other things.

---

EDIT:

As an alternative, you can use postscaler factor of 3 (CPUDIV=01) giving a 32MHz system clock. Then you will automatically get FCPU/4 from the CLKO pin (RA6) which should be 8MHz 50% duty cycle. Plus then you have a nice PIC running at 32MHz internally to do anything else you might need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment re instruction timing on my approach.  You're quite right.  I looked at the PIC18 but was trying to avoid it because of the cost.  Nice answer BTW.

Comment: There's this pesky note on [page marked 387](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf#page=389): " _When 2.0V < VDD < 3.3V, the maximum crystal frequency = (16.36 MHz/V)(VDD – 2.0V) + 4 MHz._ "; which I read as limiting input frequency to slightly less than 20MHz at the lower limit of my 3.3V(±10%) power supply range. Also, the power consumption is non-trivial.